# Probability of getting 2 tails out of 5 tosses of a coin

Tags: probability

Consider three coins having the probability of obtaining a single head in a single trial as $\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{3}{4}$. A player selects one of these three coins at random(each coin is equally likely to be selected). If the player tosses the selected coin five times independently, then the probability of obtaining two tails in five tosses is qual to.?

probability of selected each coin is $\frac{1}{3}$

so $\frac{1}{3}\left( {5 \choose2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}\right)+\frac{1}{3} \left( {5 \choose2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left( {5 \choose2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{3}\right)=\frac{85}{384}$

I dont have answer for it can anybody confirm my way of doing this question?

Comment: Let $A = \{ \text{two tails in 5 tosses} \}$ and the coins labeled $C_1,C_2,C_3)$ then
$$ P(A) = P(A| C_1)P(C_1) + P(A|C_2)P(C_2) + P(A|C_3)P(C_3).  $$
As you mentioned, $P(C_i) = 1/3$. The rest is just using the binomial distribution which looks fine.

Comment: @Gregory Can you u please confirm if my answer is correct thats all I want .Can you do little bit of maths at ur end to confirm please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this

```
> 1/3*dbinom(2, 5, 1/4)+1/3*dbinom(2, 5, 1/2)+1/3*dbinom(2, 5, 3/4)
[1] 0.2213542
> 85/384
[1] 0.2213542
```

It looks correct.

Comment: $0.5$ was not in the [options](https://prnt.sc/1001w4c)

Comment: Thanks for the info